# Custom ActiveJob adapter won't process mailer jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have an ActiveJob adapter I wrote that looks like this:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

module ActiveJob
  module QueueAdapters
    class SqsAdapter
      class << self
        def enqueue(job)
          sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
          sqs.send_message(
            queue_url: ENV['SQS_QUEUE_URL'],
            message_body: MultiJson.dump(job.serialize)
          )
        end
      end

      class JobWrapper
        class << self
          def perform(job_data)
            ActiveJob::Base.execute job_data
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run a mailer job through it (e.g. `UserMailer.registration_email(user).deliver_now`), my log output looks like this:

> Processing job e0f6afac-7b95-40c7-89d0-d9c63b808198 wrong number of
>   arguments (1 for 3+) {"job_class"=>"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob",
>   "job_id"=>"e0f6afac-7b95-40c7-89d0-d9c63b808198",
>   "queue_name"=>"mailers", "arguments"=>["UserMailer",
>   "registration_email", "deliver_now",
>   {"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://my-cms/RetailUser/863"}], "locale"=>"en"}

How come my adapter doesn't like mailer jobs, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't really see how that's relevant.

Comment: can you provide a backtrace ?